# Microcontroller Automated Heating Process

Tags: arduino, voltage-regulator, automation

I am working on a project that requires precise temperature control of a heating pad. Currently, the heating pad is directly connected to a power supply and I used thermo coupler chips with a Arduino Uno to monitor the surface temperature of the heating pad.

The application requires the temperature to be 70 degrees Celsius. In the past, I am basically twisting the knobs of the power supply and check on the Arduino serial monitor for temperature reading. As you can imagine, this process is very tedious and time consuming.

How can I regulate the voltages coming out of the supply and going into the heating pad? Possibly a chip that connects to power supply and controlled by Arduino, so I can combine that with thermo coupler program to increase and decrease voltage inputs and outputs.

I am using various heating pads, but most of them operates between 7-10VDC, 0.5-1.5A. Power supply is a 10A 30V 300W linear DC supply.

Comment: Research PID (proportional, integral, derivative) control methods.  The Arduino is more than powerful enough to control this.  Just need to sample temperature, process it through a PID algorithm, and output a control signal to increase or decrease the heat.

Comment: There are at least two PID libraries under "Device Control" on the arduino.cc site that I can see, and I'm sure there are more in different categories.

Comment: FWIW you can buy simple controllers that will handle this for you.

Comment: Heat control is usually highly overdamped.  Big thermal masses usually need that to prevent oscillations.  Personally, I'd go to Omega Instruments, and buy a cheap temperature controller.  They work, and they work well.

Comment: https://www.omega.com/en-us/control-monitoring/controllers/pid-controllers/cn740-series/p/CN743 Just add the appropriate thermocouple, and you're pretty much done for ~$150 --- and it will work fine moments after the box arrives.